# Java increasing Total amount from a TXT file

Tags: java, double

Attempting to have the balance amount being shown with total amount, the text file is formatted like so:

```
12
-10.20
5.00
```

and the code loop for this as follows
 the main part of this I'm trying to have a total amount of the balance. and its returning value but it seems to be printing out 0.00,

```
public static double BalanceCheck(String FileName, String Returned) {
    try {
        ArrayList<String> Trains = new ArrayList<String>();         
        int count = 0;
        double Balance = 0;
        File file = new File(FileName);
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {


                if(line.startsWith("-")){
                    String templine = line.replace("-", "");
                    Balance = Double.parseDouble(templine);
                    Balance -=  Balance;
                }
                else{
                    String tempBalance = line;
                    Balance = Double.parseDouble(tempBalance);
                    Balance += Balance;
                }
                System.out.println(Balance);


        }
    Balance = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.####").format(Balance));
    return Balance;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return (Double) null;
    }
```

Comment: Parse double should be able to parse a line with a negative at the start, so you can simply add the parsed double each time. Additionally, I'd recommend using java.util.Scanner; create the Scanner with a FileInputStream, and then you can simply call `scanner.nextDouble()` until you've consumed all input (`!scanner.hasNextDouble()`). Oh, another note: Java convention is for local variables and parameters to have an initial lowercase letter (e.g. `balance`, `fileName`).

Comment: Uh, what's `String Returned`, why is it not being used, and why are you returning null cast into a Double? Also, a Double is slightly different to a double. And there's a line where you're turning Balance to a formatted string, and then parsing it back into a Double again; seems unnecessary. What's the intention there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that should do good things. Note the issues I highlighted in comments on the original post, also.

```
public static double getBalance(String fileName) {
    double balance = 0.0;
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            balance += scanner.nextDouble();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (scanner != null) {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
    return balance;
}
```

Comment: Hey, yea I've just been re using code like no tomorrow, so half the stuff in there is redundant. i never though to use a file scanner. such an easier method